# how to avoid page blink after page refresh by using setTimeout javascript function?

Tags: javascript, css

```
<body id="container" onload="javascript:abc()">

 <script type="text/javascript">
    function abc(){
            setTimeout(function () {
            location.reload();
            }, 1000);

    }
 </script>
```

The above function works fine with all the browsers and page is refreshed after one second but get the page blink after every page refresh.

Is there any way to avoid page blink only with javascript ?

Comment: Dont reload the page... Use AJAX to update just the data...

Comment: You are basically asking the browser to reparse DOM, re-apply the CSS and re-interpret all the JS instantly? I don't think the tech's there yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
        setInterval(abc, 1000);

        function abc() {
        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        document.getElementById("container").innerHTML = this.responseText;
        }
        };
        xhttp.open("GET", "notify.asp", true);
        xhttp.send();
        }
    </script>
     <body id="container" onload="javascript:abc()">
```

This works perfect for me

Comment: Probably because that **is** ajax.

Answer (score 2):

In short, no.

You're refreshing a page, so making the browser go and get everything again. The reason it's quicker and blinking, instead of loading is because all the data is cached.

What you might be able to do is change the way you're doing things. Why do you need to refresh the page every second? If it's to get new, updated data, look into [ajax](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp).

Comment: for updating data i have to do page refresh

Comment: so there's no way to stop the blinking while you are refreshing

Comment: @sagarpatil - that is not true if you know how to use AJAX

Comment: I will try this with ajax